# cannot find the object referenced by HomeView In MAUI

Tags: c#, android, maui, visual-studio-2022

Position 97:51. cannot find the object referenced by HomeView
I'm getting this exception in Release mode, in debug mode its working perfect. why?

sample code attached below

HomePage.xaml

```
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<page:CustomTabBar xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
                   xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
                   xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
                   xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
                   mc:Ignorable="d"
                   xmlns:page="clr-namespace:FieldServiceManagement.Views.Pages"
                   xmlns:local="clr-namespace:FieldServiceManagement"
                   x:Class="FieldServiceManagement.Views.Pages.HomePage"
                   xmlns:android="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Maui.Controls.PlatformConfiguration.AndroidSpecific;assembly=Microsoft.Maui.Controls"
                   android:Application.WindowSoftInputModeAdjust="Unspecified"
                   xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:FieldServiceManagement.ViewModels"
                   x:Name="HomeView"
                   SelectedTabIndex="0"
                   Shell.PresentationMode="Animated"
                   Background="{StaticResource TertiaryBrush}">
    <page:CustomTabBar.ViewContent>
        
        <!--<RefreshView Command="{Binding RefreshCommand}" IsRefreshing="{Binding IsRefreshing}" >-->
        <Grid HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
              VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
            <Grid.Margin>
                <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="Thickness">
                    <On Platform="iOS,MacCatalyst" Value="15,-35,15,0" />
                    <On Platform="Android" Value="15,0,15,0" />
                </OnPlatform>
            </Grid.Margin>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                <RowDefinition />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <!---Title/Header-->
            <Grid Grid.Row="0"
                  ColumnDefinitions="*,*,*">
                <Border Grid.Column="0"
                        HorizontalOptions="Start"
                        Style="{StaticResource EllipseBorderStyle}">
                    <Image Source="humberger_menu.png"
                           HorizontalOptions="Center"
                           VerticalOptions="Center"/>
                </Border>
                <Image Grid.Column="1"
                       Style="{StaticResource ImgBrandStyle}"/>
                <Border Grid.Column="2"
                        HorizontalOptions="End"
                        Style="{StaticResource EllipseBorderStyle}"
                        Padding="12">
                    <Image Source="user.png"
                           Aspect="AspectFit"
                           HeightRequest="30"
                           WidthRequest="30"
                           HorizontalOptions="Center"
                           VerticalOptions="Center"/>
                </Border>
            </Grid>
            <ScrollView Grid.Row="1"
                        Orientation="Vertical"
                        VerticalOptions="Fill"
                        BackgroundColor="Transparent"
                        VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Never"
                        HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Never">
                <Grid RowDefinitions="Auto,Auto"
                      VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                      Padding="0,0,0,0">

                    <VerticalStackLayout Grid.Row="0"
                                         Margin="0,20,0,0">
                        <Grid>
                            <Border Style="{StaticResource SearchBorderStyle}">
                                <Grid ColumnDefinitions="Auto,*"
                                      ColumnSpacing="20">
                                    <Image Grid.Column="0" 
                                           Source="search.png"/>
                                    <Entry Grid.Column="1" 
                                           Style="{StaticResource SearchEntryStyle}"/>
                                </Grid>
                            </Border>
                            <Border Style="{StaticResource FilterBorderStyle}">
                                <Image Source="filter.png"/>
                            </Border>
                        </Grid>
                    </VerticalStackLayout>
                    <StackLayout Grid.Row="1"
                                 Margin="0,20,0,0">
                        <ScrollView Orientation="Horizontal"
                                    VerticalOptions="Start"
                                    VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Never"
                                    HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Never"
                                    BackgroundColor="Transparent">
                            <HorizontalStackLayout Spacing="10"
                                       RadioButtonGroup.GroupName="Categories"
                                       RadioButtonGroup.SelectedValue="{Binding CategorySelectedValue}"
                                       BindableLayout.ItemsSource="{StaticResource CategoriesArray}">
                                <BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate>
                                        <RadioButton x:Name="RadioCategory" Content="{Binding .}" Value="{Binding .}">
                                            <RadioButton.ControlTemplate>
                                                <ControlTemplate>
                                                    <Grid HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                                                        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                                            <VisualStateGroupList>
                                                                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CheckedStates">
                                                                    <VisualState x:Name="Checked">
                                                                        <VisualState.Setters>
                                                                            <Setter
                                                                    TargetName="CategoryLabel"
                                                                    Property="Label.TextColor"
                                                                    Value="{StaticResource White}"/>
                                                                            <Setter
                                                                    TargetName="ChipBorderView"
                                                                    Property="Border.Background"
                                                                    Value="{StaticResource PrimaryBrush}"/>
                                                                        </VisualState.Setters>
                                                                    </VisualState>
                                                                    <VisualState x:Name="Unchecked">
                                                                        <VisualState.Setters>
                                                                            <Setter
                                                                    TargetName="CategoryLabel"
                                                                    Property="Label.TextColor"
                                                                    Value="{StaticResource Gray400}"/>
                                                                            <Setter
                                                                    TargetName="ChipBorderView"
                                                                    Property="Border.Background"
                                                                    Value="{StaticResource Gray100Brush}"/>
                                                                        </VisualState.Setters>
                                                                    </VisualState>
                                                                </VisualStateGroup>
                                                            </VisualStateGroupList>
                                                        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                                        <Border StrokeThickness="0"
                                                        x:Name="ChipBorderView"
                                                        HeightRequest="35"
                                                        WidthRequest="90">
                                                            <Border.StrokeShape>
                                                                <RoundRectangle CornerRadius="25"/>
                                                            </Border.StrokeShape>
                                                            <Label Text="{TemplateBinding Content}" 
                                                           x:Name="CategoryLabel"
                                                           HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
                                                           VerticalTextAlignment="Center"
                                                           FontFamily="RalewayRegular"
                                                           FontSize="16"/>
                                                        </Border>
                                                    </Grid>
                                                </ControlTemplate>
                                            </RadioButton.ControlTemplate>
                                        </RadioButton>
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
                            </HorizontalStackLayout>
                        </ScrollView>
                        <StackLayout VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand">
                            <ActivityIndicator x:Name="Loader" IsRunning="{Binding IsLoading}" IsVisible="{Binding IsLoading}" Color="{StaticResource PrimaryBrush}" />
                            <Label Text="Loading..." HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" IsVisible="{Binding IsLoading}"/>
                        </StackLayout>
                        <CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding Issues}"
            SelectionMode="None"
            VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand"
            Margin="-10,0,0,0">
                            <CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
                                <GridItemsLayout Orientation="Vertical" />
                            </CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
                            <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <VerticalStackLayout >
                                        <Border Padding="0"
        Margin="15,10,5,5"
        WidthRequest="340"
        BackgroundColor="{StaticResource Gray100}"
        Stroke="Gray"
        StrokeThickness="0"
        StrokeShape="RoundRectangle 15" >
                                            <Border.Shadow>

                                                <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="Shadow">
                                                    <On Platform="Android, WinUI">
                                                        <Shadow Radius="25" Opacity="0.2"></Shadow>
                                                    </On>
                                                    <On Platform="iOS,MacCatalyst">
                                                        <Shadow Radius="5" Opacity="0.2"></Shadow>
                                                    </On>
                                                </OnPlatform>
                                            </Border.Shadow>
                                            <Grid RowDefinitions="Auto,Auto,Auto,Auto">
                                                <StackLayout Grid.Row="0" Orientation="Horizontal" Padding="10">
                                                    <Border StrokeThickness="0"
                            BackgroundColor="{Binding ProductImgBackground}"
                            Padding="0"
                            Margin="-1" HeightRequest="50" WidthRequest="50">
                                                        <Border.StrokeShape>
                                                            <RoundRectangle CornerRadius="25"/>
                                                        </Border.StrokeShape>
                                                        <Image Source="{Binding AssigneeAvatar}"
                                Aspect="AspectFit"
                                HeightRequest="50"
                                WidthRequest="50"/>
                                                    </Border>

                                                    <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" Padding="20,0,0,0" Spacing="5">
                                                        <Label Text="{Binding IssueSummary}"
                                FontSize="25"
                                FontFamily="PoppinsRegular"
                                TextColor="{StaticResource Primary}"
                                HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand"/>
                                                        <Label Text="{Binding Assignee}"
                                HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                                FontFamily="RalewayMedium"
                                FontSize="16"
                                TextColor="Black"
                                       
                                LineBreakMode="WordWrap"/>
                                                    </StackLayout>
                                                </StackLayout>



                                                <StackLayout Grid.Row="1" Orientation="Horizontal" Padding="10">
                                                    <Image Source="location.png" HeightRequest="20" WidthRequest="20"/>
                                                    <Label  HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Text="Los Angeles" FontSize="14" TextColor="Black" LineBreakMode="NoWrap"  Padding="10,0,10,0"/>
                                                    <Image Source="phone.png" HeightRequest="20" WidthRequest="20"/>
                                                    <Label  HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Text="9988776655" FontSize="14" TextColor="Black" LineBreakMode="NoWrap"  Padding="10,0,0,0"/>
                                                </StackLayout>
                                                <StackLayout Grid.Row="2" Orientation="Horizontal" Padding="10">
                                                    <Image Source="created.png" HeightRequest="20" WidthRequest="20"/>
                                                    <Label  HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Text="{Binding CreatedDate}" FontSize="14" TextColor="Black" LineBreakMode="NoWrap"  Padding="10,0,10,0"/>
                                                    <Image Source="Target.png" HeightRequest="20" WidthRequest="20"/>
                                                    <Label  HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Text="01/Nov/23 5:00 PM" FontSize="14" TextColor="Black" LineBreakMode="NoWrap"  Padding="10,0,0,0"/>
                                                </StackLayout>
                                                <!--<StackLayout Grid.Row="3" Orientation="Horizontal" Padding="10">
                            <ImageButton Source="accept.png" HeightRequest="50" WidthRequest="50" />
                            <ImageButton Source="decline.png" HeightRequest="50" WidthRequest="50" Padding="50,0,0,0"/>
                        </StackLayout>-->
                                            </Grid>
                                            <Border.GestureRecognizers>
                                                <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding BindingContext.DetailCommand, Source={x:Reference HomeView}}" CommandParameter="{Binding .}"/>
                                            </Border.GestureRecognizers>
                                            <!--<Border.GestureRecognizers>
                                                <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="HandleTap" />
                                            </Border.GestureRecognizers>-->
                                        </Border>

                                    </VerticalStackLayout>

                                </DataTemplate>
                            </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                        </CollectionView>
                    </StackLayout>
                </Grid>
            </ScrollView>
        </Grid>
        <!--</RefreshView>-->
    </page:CustomTabBar.ViewContent>
</page:CustomTabBar>`
```

HomeViewModel.cs

```
`using FieldServiceManagement.Models;
using FieldServiceManagement.Utility;
using FieldServiceManagement.Views;

namespace FieldServiceManagement.ViewModels
{
    [INotifyPropertyChanged]
    public partial class HomeViewModel : BaseViewModel
    {
        [ObservableProperty]
        ObservableCollection<IssueModel> _issues;
        ObservableCollection<IssueModel> AllIssues;
        public string[] Categories { get; set; }

        [ObservableProperty]
        public string _categorySelectedValue;
        private bool isLoading;

        public bool IsLoading
        {
            get { return isLoading; }
            set { SetProperty(ref isLoading, value); }
        }
        partial  void OnCategorySelectedValueChanged(string value)
        {
            UpdateIssues(value);
            Debug.WriteLine(value);
        }
        public async Task UpdateIssues(string value)
        {
            if (value == "In Progress")
                value = "work in progress";
            else if (value == "Completed")
                value = "done";
            CategorySelectedValue = value;
            Issues = new ObservableCollection<IssueModel>(AllIssues.Where(x => x.Status.ToLower() == value.ToLower()).ToList());
        }
        public HomeViewModel()
        {
            //IssueModel dummyReference = new IssueModel();
            DetailCommand = new Command(OnDetailCommand);
        }
        public ICommand DetailCommand { get; }
        private async void OnDetailCommand(object obj)
        {
            try
            {
                //Logger.Information($"Info: {obj}");
                await Shell.Current.GoToAsync($"DetailPage", new Dictionary<string, object> { ["SelectedTicket"] = (IssueModel)obj });
                //await Shell.Current.GoToAsync($"//{nameof(DetailPage)}");
                

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Error: {ex.Message}");
                await Shell.Current.GoToAsync($"//{nameof(ExceptionPage)}?data={ex.Message}");
                //Logger.Error($"Error: {ex.Message}");

            }
            
        }

        public override async Task Initialize()
        {
            StartLoading();
            CategorySelectedValue = "Pending";
            Categories = Enum.GetNames(typeof(StatusCategory)).Cast<string>().Select(x => x.ToString()).ToArray();
            AllIssues = await Common.GetAllIssues();
            Issues = new ObservableCollection<IssueModel>(AllIssues.Where(x => x.Status == "Pending").ToList());
            
            //Debug.WriteLine(Issues);
            StopLoading();
            //return Task.CompletedTask;
        }
        private async void StartLoading()
        {
            IsLoading = true;
        }

        private async void StopLoading()
        {
            IsLoading = false;
        }

        public override Task Stop()
        {
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }
        [RelayCommand]
        async Task ProductSelected(IssueModel task)
        {
            await Shell.Current.GoToAsync($"detail?", new Dictionary<string, object> { ["SelectedTicket"] = task });
        }
        private bool isRefreshing;

        public bool IsRefreshing
        {
            get => isRefreshing;
            set => SetProperty(ref isRefreshing, value);
        }

        public ICommand RefreshCommand => new Command(async () => await RefreshData());

        private async Task RefreshData()
        {
            IsRefreshing = true;
            AllIssues = await Common.GetAllIssues();
            Issues = new ObservableCollection<IssueModel>(AllIssues.Where(x => x.Status == CategorySelectedValue).ToList());
            IsRefreshing = false;
        }
    }
}`
```

IssueModel.cs

```
`using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace FieldServiceManagement.Models
{
    public class IssueModel
    {
        public string IssueKey { get; set; }
        public string IssueSummary { get; set; }
        public string Reporter { get; set; }
        public string Status { get; set; }
        public string CreatedDate { get; set; }
        public string RequestType { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public string Assignee {  get; set; }
        

        public List<AttachmentModel> Attachments {get; set;}
        public List<CommentModel> Comments { get; set; }
    }
}`
```

Issue happen only in release mode. in debug mode its working fine ,How to resolve this issue in release mode?

Comment: Try changing the linker settings for release mode to match debug mode

Comment: Tried same, but not working

Comment: <Border.GestureRecognizers>
    <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding BindingContext.DetailCommand, Source={x:Reference HomeView}}" CommandParameter="{Binding .}"/>
</Border.GestureRecognizers>

i think the issue is with this event.
CommandParameter is Binding null in release mode

Comment: Why are some properties in your HomeViewModel using CommunityToolkit and others not? Similarly, why use ICommand, then, later use [RelayCommand]? Please take the time to clean up your code and include only what you think is necessary. There are two bindings in your TapGestureReccognizer. As to the actual problem, I think you should use `x:DataType` to help validate and optimize your code better at compile time. This will minimize Debug/Release oddities.

Comment: Tried same, but not working

<Border.GestureRecognizers> <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding BindingContext.DetailCommand, Source={x:Reference HomeView}}" CommandParameter="1"/> </Border.GestureRecognizers>

unable to pass any values through CommandParameter in Release mode

Comment: Did you try to use the relative binding?

Comment: yes tried same. but same issue
                                            <TapGestureRecognizer 
Command="{Binding Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type vm:HomeViewModel}}, Path=GoToDetailsCommand}"
CommandParameter="{Binding .}"/>